# C++ how to create a PNG file with known data?

Tags: c++, png

Just wondering, if I read a PNG file as a binary file, and I know how to write the hex numbers into another plain txt or whatever file, then how can I recreate the PNG file with those hex numbers?

This is the code I use to read from a PNG file and write to another plain txt file:

```
unsigned char x;
ifile.open("foo.png",ios::binary);
ifile>>noskipws>>hex;
while(ifile>>x){
  ofile<<setw(2)<<setfill('0')<<(int)x;
  //do some formatting stuff to the ofile, ofile declaration omitted
  //some ifs to see if IEND is read in, which is definitely correct
  //if IEND, break, so the last four hex numbers in ofile are 49 45 4E 44
}
//read another 4 bytes and write to ofile, which are AE 42 60 82, the check sum
```

The reason why I am doing this is because I have some PNG files which have some irrelevant messages after IEND chunk, and I want to get rid of them and only keep the chunks related to the actual picture and split them into different files. By "irrelevant messages" I mean they are not the actual part of the picture but I have some other use with them.

Comment: This question seems to be based on the wrong assumption that a binary file, such as a png, is the same as a human-readable list of hex numbers.

Comment: This piece of code is working as intended, it outputs a plain text file in which the hex numbers of the PNG file are. I have a hex reader, I can confirm it is outputting the right thing. I just do not know how to put them together to make a PNG file. @DrewDormann

Comment: Just reverse the operations. Read in two characters then convert to binary.

Comment: Do you mean to write 0 and 1 bits to a file as binary?@CaptainObvlious

Comment: You should discuss this with the `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, you just need to read every 2 characters and convert them from hex back to binary.

```
unsigned char x;
char buf[3] = {0};
ifile.open("foo.hex");
while(ifile>>buf[0]>>buf[1]){
    char *end;
    x = (unsigned char) strtol(buf, &end, 16);
    if (*end == 0) // no conversion error
        // output the byte
```